# SVG styling issue occurs second time onwards : chrome only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, svg

This is a weird issue.

I am having a SVG on my page

```js
function addClone()
{
    //loadXMLDoc();
    var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
    var selected = document.getElementById("ID_obj8e530fe7-9e8b-474e-a48b-9c26418b84a6");
    var targetElement = selected.cloneNode(true);
    var namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var dummySvg = document.createElementNS(namespace, "svg");
    dummySvg.appendChild(targetElement);
    svg.appendChild(dummySvg);
    //Doing my stuff here with newly appended dummy element.
    debugger;
    svg.removeChild(dummySvg);            
}
```

```html
<div id="svg_cont">
        <svg id="svg" class="main-svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 380" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
            <defs>
            </defs>
            <g id="layerWrapper" class="svg-view" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1)">
                <svg id="mySection" class="section-view">
                    <g id="svg-view" class="svg-view">
                        <path d="M1,1 L790,1L790,610L1,610Z" class="svg-drawing-boundary"></path>
                        <svg id="ID_obj8e530fe7-9e8b-474e-a48b-9c26418b84a6" class="prj-asset prj-obj cursor-move">
                            <g transform="translate(267.15603585942523,116.72438293625564)rotate(345,72.94356588618024,44.27289336989671)skewX(0)scale(11.011481407032758,6.1897008108322416)">
                                <svg xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                     width="13.248637" height="14.106602" viewBox="0 0 10.59891 11.285281" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st3"
                                     id="svg3041" version="1.1" style="font-size:12px;fill:none;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:3;overflow:visible"> 
                                <style type="text/css" id="style3043">
                                    .st1 {
                                        fill: url(#grad0-4);
                                        stroke: #000000;
                                        stroke-linecap: round;
                                        stroke-linejoin: round;
                                        stroke-width: 0.72;
                                    }

                                    .st2 {
                                        fill: #ffffff;
                                        font-family: Arial;
                                        font-size: 0.666664em;
                                    }

                                    .st3 {
                                        fill: none;
                                        fill-rule: evenodd;
                                        font-size: 12px;
                                        overflow: visible;
                                        stroke-linecap: square;
                                        stroke-miterlimit: 3;
                                    }
                                    </style> 
                                <defs id="Patterns_And_Gradients"> 
                                <linearGradient id="grad0-4" x1="-0.36884788" y1="586.81169" x2="10.490556" y2="586.81169" gradientTransform="scale(0.97601216,1.0245774)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
                                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ff00ff" stop-opacity="1" id="stop3047"></stop> 
                                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00ffff" stop-opacity="1" id="stop3049"></stop> 
                                    </linearGradient> 
                                </defs> 
                                <g v:index="2" id="g3051" transform="translate(0.36000001,-601.07501)"> 
                                <g id="shape3133-1"> <title id="title3056">Unit 1</title> <desc id="desc3058">1</desc> 
                                <v:textblock v:margins="rect(5,4,4,2.5)"></v:textblock> <v:textrect cx="4.93945" cy="606.797" width="9.88" height="10.4063"></v:textrect> 
                                <rect x="0" y="601.59399" width="9.8789101" height="10.4063" class="st1" id="rect3060" style="fill:url(#grad0-4);stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.72000003;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round"></rect> 
                                <text x="4.5" y="609.70001" class="st2" id="text3062" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Arial; text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px;">A</text> 
                                            </g> 
                                            </g> 
                                        </svg>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                        <svg id="ID_obj825f0b13-b5f1-42d2-813f-115805a1f5ea" class="prj-asset prj-obj cursor-move">
                            <g transform="translate(477.2921885223701,123.05810552726564)rotate(0,40.924776199309576,58.01807016243163)skewX(0)scale(6.177956123046479,8.111382018451938)">
                                <svg xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                     width="13.248637" height="14.106602" viewBox="0 0 10.59891 11.285281" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st3"
                                     id="svg3041" version="1.1" style="font-size:12px;fill:none;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:3;overflow:visible"> 
                                <style type="text/css" id="style3043">
                                    .st1 {
                                        fill: url(#grad0-4);
                                        stroke: #000000;
                                        stroke-linecap: round;
                                        stroke-linejoin: round;
                                        stroke-width: 0.72;
                                    }

                                    .st2 {
                                        fill: #ffffff;
                                        font-family: Arial;
                                        font-size: 0.666664em;
                                    }

                                    .st3 {
                                        fill: none;
                                        fill-rule: evenodd;
                                        font-size: 12px;
                                        overflow: visible;
                                        stroke-linecap: square;
                                        stroke-miterlimit: 3;
                                    }
                                    </style> 
                                <defs id="Patterns_And_Gradients"> 
                                <linearGradient id="grad0-4" x1="-0.36884788" y1="586.81169" x2="10.490556" y2="586.81169" gradientTransform="scale(0.97601216,1.0245774)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
                                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ff00ff" stop-opacity="1" id="stop3047"></stop> 
                                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00ffff" stop-opacity="1" id="stop3049"></stop> 
                                            </linearGradient> 
                                            </defs> 
                                <g v:index="2" id="g3051" transform="translate(0.36000001,-601.07501)"> <g id="shape3133-1"> 
                                <title id="title3056">Unit 1</title> <desc id="desc3058">1</desc> 
                                <v:textblock v:margins="rect(5,4,4,2.5)"></v:textblock> 
                                <v:textrect cx="4.93945" cy="606.797" width="9.88" height="10.4063"></v:textrect> 
                                <rect x="0" y="601.59399" width="9.8789101" height="10.4063" class="st1" id="rect3060" style="fill:url(#grad0-4);stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.72000003;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round"></rect>
                                <text x="4.5" y="609.70001" class="st2" id="text3062" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Arial; text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px;">C</text> 
                                            </g> 
                                            </g> 
                                        </svg>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                        <svg id="ID_objdb7111ea-a3eb-4747-abbc-52dc05a80a75" class="prj-asset prj-obj cursor-move">
                            <g transform="translate(137.62939022284382,148.43016162573252)rotate(43,39.73522235650188,37.15088161767568)skewX(0)scale(5.998387475707924,5.193986990973449)">
                                <svg xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                     width="13.248637" height="14.106602" viewBox="0 0 10.59891 11.285281" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st3"
                                     id="svg3041" version="1.1" style="font-size:12px;fill:none;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:3;overflow:visible"> 
                                <style type="text/css" id="style3043">
                                    .st1 {
                                        fill: url(#grad0-4);
                                        stroke: #000000;
                                        stroke-linecap: round;
                                        stroke-linejoin: round;
                                        stroke-width: 0.72;
                                    }

                                    .st2 {
                                        fill: #ffffff;
                                        font-family: Arial;
                                        font-size: 0.666664em;
                                    }

                                    .st3 {
                                        fill: none;
                                        fill-rule: evenodd;
                                        font-size: 12px;
                                        overflow: visible;
                                        stroke-linecap: square;
                                        stroke-miterlimit: 3;
                                    }
                                    </style> 
                                <defs id="Patterns_And_Gradients"> 
                                <linearGradient id="grad0-4" x1="-0.36884788" y1="586.81169" x2="10.490556" y2="586.81169" gradientTransform="scale(0.97601216,1.0245774)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
                                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ff00ff" stop-opacity="1" id="stop3047"></stop> 
                                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#00ffff" stop-opacity="1" id="stop3049"></stop> 
                                            </linearGradient> 
                                            </defs> 
                                <g v:index="2" id="g3051" transform="translate(0.36000001,-601.07501)"> <g id="shape3133-1">
                                <title id="title3056">Unit 1</title> <desc id="desc3058">1</desc> 
                                <v:textblock v:margins="rect(5,4,4,2.5)"></v:textblock> 
                                <v:textrect cx="4.93945" cy="606.797" width="9.88" height="10.4063"></v:textrect> 
                                <rect x="0" y="601.59399" width="9.8789101" height="10.4063" class="st1" id="rect3060" style="fill:url(#grad0-4);stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.72000003;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round"></rect> 
                                <text x="4.5" y="609.70001" class="st2" id="text3062" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Arial; text-anchor: middle; font-size: 8px;">B</text> </g> </g> </svg>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="addClone();" />
    </div>
```

Note : To build it quick in this snippet I added a button instead of selection of element.
**- To reproduce this issue - run this snippet on chrome browser and click on the button 2 times. keep your developer window open so it can reach to debugger.**

On selection of any svg element, I am doing below process in my js.

Cloning the selected element, applying some transformation on cloned element doing some other process and then appending that to my main svg. After appending cloned element to my main svg, I am calculating its bounding box and then processing that for my requirement.

Once my task is completed, I am removing that added clone element from my main svg.

The problem occurs when I remove the cloned element – its removing style effect (specially Pattern and Gradient effect) from all the elements on the svg, Although all elements are having its style and Pattern and Gradient within them. 
If I go to source and then my original svg is unchanged.

This issue does not occur for first time but starts from second time onwards.

I can see all my svg elements are having exact same `<defs>` and `<style>` that may be the issue but I can’t change the way original svg elements looks like – its having style, defs and other stuff which can’t be modified (as they are custom. Users can create their own template and upload in the system and then later on they can have those on the page).

When I tried creating a sample fiddle/snippet in this post, it is working fine. When I tried to debug that, it is creating the same issue as I am having in my application (in my application, its occurring even on run without debug).

Using d3 js, browser: chrome, working fine in Mozilla.

Comment: You're not allowed multiple elements in the same document with the same id. your clone & appendChild does just that.

Comment: Creating a dummy svg element with no id, and then wrapping up cloned svg element in that  - i also tried to have unique id for that dummy svg but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this and similar behavior before in Chrome and other Browsers, basically this is what seems to happen:

When you create the SVG and the browser internally parses the representation it resolves the references to the defs sections (those elements that use `url(#someId)` and wires up the internal references to point to these elements.

Now if you clone the SVG you get more elements with the same ID in the same document so the references become ambiguous. However most browser engines are still happy with that (as far as I remember there have also been version of the various browsers where the implementations refused to resolve to any element and instead they showed the SVG as if there was no reference at all, which resulted in black fills and no gradients most of the time, but sometimes also missing elements in the case of `use` elements).

Chrome however seems to be happy and internally references one of the target elements (the first one?). Now the problem is when you remove the element that Chrome currently targets. The implementation can notice this and will remove the internal reference, not trying to see if there is actually *another* element with the same id in the document (there should not be one, anyway). Not having an element that it can resolve to, it behaves as if the link was pointing to a non-existing element and renders the corresponding default graphic.

I see multiple possible solutions here if you need to deal with user content. We implemented those solutions for our commercial library, too, and they worked well for all browsers:

a) Don't clone the defs sections but accumulate all different defs sections. Separate the defs elements from the real "content" and only clone the content. Remove ids in the "content" sections.

b) Resolve references and the corresponding IDs and adjust them using new, non-clashing ids.

c) Encode the complete custom SVG into a data URL and include it in an svg `image` tag in your container SVG. This way you basically get multiple documents each with their own id namespace so they will not clash if copied. This also prevents Cross Site Scripting attacks, since Javascript and all other things will basically be sand-boxed and cannot access to your HTML document anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation and possible solutions.